# calling debug(myfun1) within the debugger

Tags: r, rstudio

Say my code looks as follows

```
myfun1 = function()
{
  print("This is myfun1, before calling the myfun2()")
  myfun2()
  print("This is myfun1, after calling the myfun2()")
}

myfun2 = function()
{
  print("This is myfun2, before calling the myfun3()")
  myfun3()
  print("This is myfun2, after calling the myfun3()")
}

myfun3 = function()
{
  print("This is myfun3(), before calling the myfun3()")
  myfun4()
  print("This is myfun3(), after calling the myfun3()")
}

myfun4 = function()
{
  print("This is myfun4()")
}
```

I have sourced it and am in the middle of debugging it using,

```
> source('~/Desktop/foo1.R')
> debug(myfun1)
> myfun1()
debugging in: myfun1()
debug at ~/Desktop/foo1.R#2: {
    print("This is myfun1, before calling the myfun2()")
    myfun2()
    print("This is myfun1, after calling the myfun2()")
}
Browse[2]>
```

Note that I am at Browse[2] since I started with myfun1() and on single stepping through the code using **'n'**, it would take me to Browse[3], Browse[4] and Browse[5] for myfun2(), myfun3() and myfun4() respectively. That's fine.

**However, instead of stepping using 'n', at Browse[2] , if I once again call myfun1(), this is what I get**

```
Browse[2]> myfun1()
debugging in: myfun1()
debug at ~/Desktop/foo1.R#2: {
    print("This is myfun1, before calling the myfun2()")
    myfun2()
    print("This is myfun1, after calling the myfun2()")
}
Browse[4]>
```

I have two questions here :

1. Firstly, why is such recursive debugging (in a separate tab kinda) allowed? How is
   it useful?
2. Second, why is that I get **Browse[4]** here? I would have expected to get Browse[3] since we are at 2 now.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably expecting `Browse[n]` to mean the depth of the current call stack. It is *almost* true. See the documentation entry for `?browser`:

> The browser prompt is of the form Browse[n]>: here var{n} indicates the ‘browser level’. The browser can be called when browsing (and often is when debug is in use), and each recursive call increases the number. (The actual number is the number of ‘contexts’ on the context stack: this is usually 2 for the outer level of browsing and 1 when examining dumps in debugger.)

Note that you start with `Browser[2]` (as mentioned in the last sentence of the help paragraph above), i.e. a single call creates 2 ‘contexts’. That's why a recursive call creates another 2 and the total number is 4, not 3.

Now, why is it allowed? The answer is why not. When you are standing inside `browser()`, you can essentially do whatever you want using full R functionality. Say, you manually print or dump variables, examine them to see what's going on. It would be strange to forbid printing something if you are debugging using `debug(print)`, wouldn't it? More than that, forbidding recursive calls in this context doesn't seem like a very simple task to do from a language perspective, and we are clearly lacking a solid reason for that.

Comment: can I say that this kinda recursive debugging is allowed because this is scripting and we are ultimately working on a terminal(shell). Say something like C, wouldn't allow it because it's a programming language?